# A multiplicative Taylor theorem?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, approximation

In a first calculus course it is often that one learns about the Taylor polynomials

$$f(x) \approx \sum_{k=0}^{N}\frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)(x-x_0)^k}{k!}$$

Which provide increasingly better approximation to a function which needs to be differentiable at the point as many times as the highest exponent. ($f^{(n)}(x_0)$ must exist).

---

Now to my question. What happens if we replace the sum by a product? Is there some concept we can use to create a multiplicative refinement as contrary to an additive one?

$$f(x) \approx \prod_{k=0}^N\mathcal F \{f,k,x_0\}(x)$$

Can we derive what this $\mathcal F$ thing (functional?) could be for this to make sense, and what must we demand of $f$ to hold on or around $x_0$?

Comment: If $g(x) = \ln f(x)$ is defined, $$\mathcal{F}(f,k,x_0)(x) = \exp\left( \frac{g^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!} (x-x_0)^k \right)$$ (what a sharp observation :p)

Comment: Not what you ask for, but look up *Pade approximation* for a rational extension of the idea of Taylor series.

Comment: @Cauchy: $\frac{\partial^k}{\partial x^k}\left\{\log(f(x))\right\}$ will be giving chain rule effects. for example k=1: $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$, but I think it may be on the right track. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx+ln(f(x))

Comment: @Chappers sounds interesting, thanks!

Comment: @mathreadler Not sure if it is of interest, but $\frac{\partial^k}{\partial x^k}\log(f)$ may be computed using [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula).

Comment: Entire analytic/holomorphic functions admit ``factorizations'' involving their zeroes. These are products of the kind you are asking about. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: I do remember checking out that formula a few years ago but that was before I had read about integer partitions. Now suddenly it seems more intuitive.

Comment: :o and maybe now I'll go look up integer partitions :)

Comment: @ABlumenthal: wow that looks cool. I will check it out!

Comment: @mathreadler You might also be interested in the "product integral" of Volterra (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral).  A product "anti-derivative" is an infinitesimal version of a product representation for a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding a comment to an answer to highlight an interesting application. The [Weierstrass Factorization Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem) is a way of representing an entire holomorphic function as an infinite product in terms of its growth rate at infinity and its zeroes.

I don't quite remember the chain of events, but Euler was the first to write down the product formula

$$
\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x} = \prod_{n = 1}^\infty \bigg( 1 - \frac{x^2}{n^2} \bigg) \, .
$$

The Taylor series of the right-hand side expands as $1 - \frac{(\pi x)^2}{3!} + O(x^4)$, whereas the "monomial expansion" (glossing over how to make sense of that rigorously) of the right-hand side is of the form $1 - \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{x^2}{n^2} + O(x^4)$. Equating the $x^2$ terms yields Euler's (first) solution to the Basel problem,
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}
$$

Comment: Yes, I suppose Weierstrass factorization is the closest to an answer I have gotten so far. That is also a very interesting way to come up with the $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ The only one I knew so far was the Fourier transform of some function ( which one I have forgotten ). I wonder if one can make a connection from that transform to the product above.